# JS 'reload' div element content without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, charts

I have cart from chartJS using canvas.

[image]

When I hover on my site's sidebar, page layout changes and the chart can't fit box anymore because it's dimensions are bigger than white box dimensions.

This lines are getting out of white box.

But when I reload page at this point, than everything fits perfect.

My question:

Is there a way to add event or something, when I hover on sidebar that chart element  width gets updated, or to reload that element so it can automatically fit box, whithout refreshing page?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `mouseover` event, you can use one of those:

```
let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  
// This handler will be executed only once when the cursor
// moves over the unordered list
sidebar.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {   
  // call chartJS here
});
```

```
let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");

// This handler will be executed every time the cursor
// is moved over a different list item
sidebar.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {   
  // call chartJS here
});
```

For more information about events visit this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events